# Failed to Solr indexing with json including date field

Tags: java, json, date, solr

### My goal

I want to post my json file for indexing. When I specify the field as `string`, post and index success, but if I do it as `tdates`, `tdate` or `date`, it fail.
I will use date value for faceting.

### Environment

CentOS 7, Solr 5.4

### What I did

Prepare the managed-schema. The portion of code is the following:

```
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="false" />
<field name="record_date" type="xxxx" indexed="false" stored="false" docValues="true" />
```

When xxxx is `string`, indexing success and `tdates`, `tdate` or `date` failed.

(Ofcourse `tdates`, `tdate` and `date` are defined in managed-schema. 
e.g. `<fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0" />`)

And the portion of posting json is the following:

```
{"name":"Calendar", "record_date":"2015-11-30T00:00:00Z"},
{"name":"Clock", "record_date":"2015-12-01T11:05:00Z"}
```

I execute the command like the following(in the solr root dir): `bin/post -c mycorename ~/myfile.json`

After that, I got the error like the following:

```
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url: http://xxxx:8983/solr/mycorename/update/json/docs
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: {"responseHeader":{"status":400, "QTime":7},"error":{"msg":"Invalid Date String:'Mon Nov 30 00:00:00 UTC 2015'","code":400}}
SimplePostToll: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://xxxx:8983/solr/mycorename/update/json/docs
1 files indexed.
COOMITing Solr index changes to http://xxxx:8983/solr/mycorename/update...
Time spent: 0:00:00.102
```

### Refs and comments

I checked this document [Working with Dates](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates) and so I update my JSON date value `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ` style, but it is not working.

I also tried to post json appended escape-sequence ver like the following:

```
{"name":"Calendar", "record_date":"2015-11-30T00\:00\:00Z"},
{"name":"Clock", "record_date":"2015-12-01T11\:05\:00Z"}
```

But the error message is completely same before.

I found one thing on the error message. It says `"Invalid Date String:'Mon Nov 30 00:00:00 UTC 2015'"` and this date value is not the same format with my json value.
I guess Solr couverts the date value before indexing and as a result indexed value is string value, NOT date value, so I get this message.

What was wrong with me? How can I fix it... any ideas?